# View all previous IP logs/connections/etc

Tags: networking, log, syslog, monitoring

I'm not sure if this is a thing or not. I was wondering if for example someone got on my machine (say its on a vpn not on my home network) If someone had access to it somehow if they could view any previous log files that would show them what IPs the machine has connected to in the past, or any VPNs it has connected to. Is there a log file anywhere in ubuntu/debian that shows all its previous connections?

Comment: Have a look in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

Yes, they can … even if your machine is on VPN.

#### Longer answer

One log file for all outgoing IPs system-wide by default? The answer is no, ... that's part of what is called auditing which is not enabled by default on Ubuntu ... **BUT**, the apps that connect to Internet or manage the connection to Internet like *web browsers, email clients, download managers, bittorrent clients, VPN clients, network managers, DNS clients, firewalls ... etc.* have their own log files that might very well contain some or all of the outgoing IPs among other things that they log … even system and kernel logs might contain connection information and outgoing IPs as well... and while most of the logs are under the `/var/log/` directory or managed by systemd’s journal system that can be queried by the [journalctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) utility, they could be anywhere else if the maintainer of a certain package decided so … please see [Linux log files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) and [viewing and monitoring Ubuntu log files](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#1-overview) for a hint.